# Equivalent to header('X-Accel-Buffering: no') in Openlitespeed to disable output buffering?

Tags: php, nginx, litespeed

I am moving from NGINX to Openlitespeed. On NGINX to stream a file (php readfile()) I could use header('X-Accel-Buffering: no'); to disable output buffering.

How would I do this on Openlitespeed? is there a setting or a special header? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you update output_buffering = 4096 to output_buffering = off from php.ini, will it works?

Comment: @Eric ill try it